# Which preposition to use in "to live in fear [...] one's life"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> I am being threatened by unsavory sorts. I am now living in fear **for** my life.

or

> I am now living in fear **of** my life.

Comment: Styx's song Renegade uses it in the correct context: "Oh, Mama, I'm in fear for my life from the long arm of the law."

Answer (score 12):

**The prescriptivist's answer is:**

*Fear **of** xxx* is the emotion you feel when you worry that *xxx* might **cause harm**.

> *Arachnophobia* is uncontrollable fear of spiders.

*Fear **for** xxx* is the emotion you feel when you worry that *xxx* might **be harmed**.

> I fear for my family's safety.

It is a common error to say *in fear of* when you mean *in fear for*.

**The descriptivist's answer:**

Lots of people say *in fear of my life*, so it's probably okay.

Comment: +1 for prescriptivist answer, -1 for descriptivist answer. You're right in that it is possible that many people might say it (though I've never heard the phrase that way, I accept that in some areas it may be common.) I *really* want to vote you up because your prescriptivist answer is so good, but I think the point is to try to figure out what is correct, not common.  I think it's okay just to say that its wrong, and leave it at that.

Comment: -1 descriptivist as I've never heard it that way in AmE, and I would take it to mean that one was afraid of the life itself, just as in the prescriptive answer.  +1 for recognizing that there is a difference between pre/descriptive and separating the answers. +1 for the prescriptive. So +1. :P

Comment: +1, but I wish I could +3 for the same reason issues Joshua pointed out, but with different polarity on the descriptivist case. I've *definitely* heard "in fear of my life" (furthermore, prepositions, like most thinks in natural language, do not follow logic -- you can't reliable extrapolate their use in one situation, even a typical one, to their use elsewhere).

Comment: *"fear of my life"* gets 8 hits in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), vs. 19 for *"fear for my life"*, 20 for *"afraid for my life"*, and none for *"afraid of my life"*.

Comment: - 1 because you don't cite any "authority" for this prescriptivist viewpoint. "fear of one's life" is not a recent expression, at any rate: the OED gives the example "1490   Caxton tr. Eneydos xlix. 142   He lept in to one of the shippes..for grete feer of his lyffe." A logical argument like the one you present here may have gotten currency among most prescriptivists, but it might not have: prescriptivism often illogically adheres to tradition. So I don't think it's appropriate to call it a "common error" unless you have more evidence that it is commonly considered to be an error.

Answer (score 7):

I've never heard it in any form other than *I fear for*

> I am being threatened by unsavory sorts. I fear for my life.
>
> I was threatened by unsavory sorts. I now fear for my life.

Comment: +1 for the only way I've ever heard it spoken in AmE.

Answer (score 3):

Both prepositions have always been used - *"of"* is about three times more common overall, but *"for"* has been [steadily gaining ground for the past century](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20fear%20of%20his%20life,in%20fear%20for%20his%20life&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)...

[image]

I see no evidence of a US/UK difference, nor do I believe there's any conceivable different nuance of meaning. Personally I'm quite used to both forms so neither seems particularly unusual.

---

But if I stop and think about it, **for** is more consistent with related usages - *"I fear **for** my sanity"* (not *"I fear **of** my sanity"*). I'm afraid not of my life or sanity, but of the prospect of losing them.

*"Of"* works better if the noun is something I really *am* afraid of, such as my *fear **of**. flying*.

Given that support from related usages, I'd expect **for** to be the dominant form in a few decades.

Answer (score 2):

A simple "I fear for my life" should do. Or, if you want to remove the "life", then "I am living in fear" (but that's obviously not as strong).